# What is the technology behind Tadalist's "Add Todo Item"?

Tags: web-design

How does tadalist instantly add a new todo item without having to do a page refresh?

Is there a way to do a dynamic add to a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), and you can do anything with an ajax call that you can with a normal page refresh, including database updates.

Comment: so good to know!!!!!